# Bad Request: chat not found on pytest

Tags: python, telegram, юнит-тесты, pytest

При выполнении теста вылазит ошибка

> Bad Request: chat not found

Вот код теста:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'username,password,promo_access',
    [
        ('test1@lotfull.ru', 'RanksAn123!@', False),
        ('test3@lotfull.ru', '11111111', False),
        ('test2@lotfull.ru', 'simplepass', False),
        ('test4@lotfull.ru', 'simplepass123!', False),
        ('test5@lotfull.ru', 'simplepass123@', False),
        ('test3@lotfull.ru', '11111111', True),
    ]
)
def test_temp_register_login(self, username, password, promo_access):
    if promo_access:
        promo_access = PromoAccess.objects.create(
            username=username,
            duration=const.WEEKLY,
            subscription=const.ALL_INCLUSIVE_SUB,
            until_date=date.today()
        )

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.post(reverse('auth-temp-login'), {'username': 'test1'})
    temp_login_view = AuthViewSet.as_view({'post': 'temp_login'})
    response = temp_login_view(request)

    assert response.data['token'] is not None

    request = factory.post(
        reverse('auth-register'),
        {'username': username, 'password': password},
    )
    register_view = AuthViewSet.as_view({'post': 'register'})
    response = register_view(request)

    assert response.data['email_send'] == 1
    assert response.data['status'] == 'confirmation code send to email'

    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    request = factory.post(
        reverse('auth-confirm-register'),
        {'username': username, 'confirmation': user.confirmation_code},
    )
    confirm_register_view = AuthViewSet.as_view({'post': 'confirm_register'})
    response = confirm_register_view(request)
    assert response.data['status'] == 'user registered successfully'

    token = response.data['token']
    if promo_access and isinstance(promo_access, PromoAccess):
        user.refresh_from_db()
        assert user.subscription == const.ALL_INCLUSIVE_SUB

        promo_access.refresh_from_db()
        assert promo_access.granted is True

    request = factory.post(
        reverse('auth-login'),
        {'username': username, 'password': password},
    )
    login_view = AuthViewSet.as_view({'post': 'login'})
    response = login_view(request)

    assert response.data['status'] == 'login successful'
    assert response.data['token'] == token
```